# Passing complex object to WebAPI from AngularJS

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to post a JavaScript item to a C# WebAPI call using AngularJS.  Below is what I am trying to do.

Objects

```
class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }
}
```

My C# Controller function

```
    [Route("Update/")]
    public void Update(Person person)
    {
        _service.Update(person);
    }
```

AngularJS call

```
    this.update = function (person) {
        $http.post("api/Person/Update/", person);
    }
```

When I receive the object in the WebAPI controller the address is null.  Why is this data not being received?

**Edit**
I was wrong in my original question the Person object looked like this

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public IAddress address { get; set; }
}
```

When I changed address from IAddress to Address everything worked as expected.

Comment: I would guess that the model binding is failing, can you look at what POST data you are sending out? It needs to match quite exactly for the model binding to succeed.

Comment: What does `person` look like if you log it?

Answer (score 2):

Your post would be in json format which will assign person object to `person`, `Address` object must be well formed object as it contain sub properties.

**Code**

```
$scope.person = {
  'Street': '',
  'LastName': '',
  'Address': {
     'Street': '',
     'City': '',
     'State': '',
  },
}

this.update = function (person) {
    $http.post("api/Person/Update/", { person : $scope.person});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach allows to send complex objects with arrays and sub objects through HTTP GET:

Angular:

```
$http({
       url: '/myApiUrl',
       method: 'GET',
       params: { personStr: angular.toJson(person, false) }
      })
```

C#:

```
[HttpGet]
public string Get(string personStr)
{
     Person obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Person>(personStr);
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not possible, but this solution allows you to use your complex object on the .NET side. There is no body in a GET request, so you have to add your object into the URI.

Change your web api method to:

```
[Route("Update/")]
public void Update([FromUri]Person person)
{
    _service.Update(person);
}
```

Change your angular code to:

```
this.update = function (person) {
    $http.post("api/Person/Update?FirstName=John&LastName=Doe&Address%5BStreet%5D=123%20Main%20St&Address%5BCity%5D=Knoxville&Address%5BState%5D=Tennessee");
}
```